# How to create a movable point in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have the following code:

```
    function mapCreate(lon,lat){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map1");
    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");
    map.addLayer(osm);
    var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
    );

    point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(center.lon,center.lat);
    vectors.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point)]);
    drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors);
    map.addControl(drag);
    drag.activate();
    map.setCenter(center, 15);
    map.addLayer(vectors);
    point.events.register('moveend',point, function(evt){
        alert('hello');
    });

}
```

The part that does not work is:

```
        point.events.register('moveend',point, function(evt){
        alert('hello');
    });
```

Can anyone help me with creating an event listener for a point in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use onComplete property of OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature, for example:

```
drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors, {
    autoActivate: true,
    onComplete: function() {alert('hello')}
});
```

Here is my online example: [DragFeature](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/SMnUJ/).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out too. Question: It strikes me that having to pass an empty function to a control to make it work is, well...kind of dumb. What is going on here that leads to this?